# ASP.Net DotNetNuke: using pre-made websites

Tags: .net-framework, web-development, asp.net, cms

I would really appreciate any useful information in relation to this as I cannot find anything on the internet at all; despite the fact that it must be an issue that many users will encounter.

I have installed and am able to use DotNetNuke as a .Net framework CMS. I can see and edit their sample pages and create new pages.

But what I really need to be able to do is to import my own web (html) pages and CSS files.

How on earth can I start to do this? Both the import and upload options essentially ignore .html. If I can find the source code files I suppose I could start the process of copy pasting ...

Comment: Import a pre-made site inside a cms is something that sound strange. A CSM should be used to host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot really be done: at best only copy pasting elements of a premade site into the corresponding parts of a cms is achievable. Ultimately (in my opinion) it has been easier to develop from scratch. Moreover, while technologies such as javascript, css, html are standards across the web, the manner in which a particular CMS will work will be specific to that CMS. CMSs are not designed for transferability, mutability, or compatibility. They are designed to be easily extendible and update-able within the structure of their own framework.